# How do I enable SATA 3 on my computer or check if it is enabled?

Tags: motherboard, sata

My HDD is a `WD5000AAKX`, the Shop keeper told me that it is 6gb/s meaning SATA III right ?

How would I know if its working at SATA 3 6.0gb/s?

My system:

- Intel Corei7 920
- Gigabyte X58A UD7
- AMD Radeon 5830
- Adata HM750 750W 12 (60A)

Answer (score 3):

First off, per your motherboard [specs](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3527#sp) the HD will need to be plugged into either GSATA3_6, or GSATA3_7

Once it is plugged into the correct SATA port you should be able to check in the BIOS as to whatspeed the drive is connected at to confirm/set it to 6Gb/s